# how to configure log4j with multiple profiles using one log4j.xml file

Tags: spring, log4j, logback

Logback has `springProfile` tag for configur with multiple spring profiles, but i cannot find how to do same thing in Log4j.

- dev

```xml
    <logger name="org" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>
```

- real

```xml
    <logger name="org" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="async-appender"/>
    </logger>
```

Comment: unfortunately,no.spring has 'springProfile'  tag rather than logback.[spring boot issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22149)